# Manually specify page breaks on table of contents (KOMA script)

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, koma-script

I have an `scrartcl` class with a long ToC. I can visually see that the first two sections (and their subsections) would fit nicely on one page. The third section begins on that page, but only a few subsections are shown before it breaks. I would like to intervene and force a page break before the third section starts. This pattern occurs for a few other sections. Is there an easy way to tell KOMA to break page here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it along the lines below.

```
...
\tableofcontents
...
\section{First}
...
\section{Second}
...
\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage} Insert \newpage into the ToC
\section{Third}
...
```

Comment: Too easy! Thank you :)