# Preventing chapter title alone at bottom of toc ams book

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, amsbook

A chapter title appears on bottom of page in toc with section titles beginning on the next page of toc.  Is there some way to force the chapter title onto the next page?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Take a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537874  Although that question is about `scrsrtcl`, the method works as well with other classes.

Comment: Thanks so very much.  \addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}  worked perfectly.